# angular js reloading view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular JS and Angular IU-Router in my project and using a lot of ui-views. I have a situation where I need to change the language of the site, therefore I need to swap my ui-view's model to another model with the relevant language. I already have a service that detects the relevant model and passes it into the ui-view's controller. So if I can reload the ui-view, then in theory my problem would be solved.

I recall reading something about automatically reloading a ui-view (or possibly an ng-view) and re-instantiating its controller, but after much searching I haven't been able to find that information again.

Does anyone know what it is I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Take a look at `angular-translate`
https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate

2 In your case, add some `if-else` control ( `ng-if, ng-switch` etc. ) in the outer div, use the **same** `subview` in the inner div. Then change the `settings.currentLang` when the language changes may cause the subview reload (not tested).

```
<div ng-controller="containerCtrl">
    <div ng-if="settings.currentLang=='en'">
        <div ui-view='subview'></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="settings.currentLang=='ja'">
        <div ui-view='subview'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know whether either of those are necessarily practical in my case. It's not just language I have to account for when swapping out the model, but potentially location (metropolitan, country) and job role too (manager, worker). I've set up a system where my JSON data is able to extend and overwrite itself  to account for these different job roles, but if I can't find a way to swap out the model, I've got no way to display that information.